# Pesanteur et lourdeur, quelle différence ?

Tags: sens

Are they complete synonyms? *Sinon, quelles sont les différences ?*

I’ve consulted Wiktionary, *Larousse*, and *Robert*, all to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Pour répondre précisemment à cette question il faudrait avoir plus de détails sur le contexte dans lequel ces mots sont employés.

Le terme "pesanteur" est le plus souvent utilisé dans un contexte scientifique (physique). Son utilisation dans un autre contexte est possible mais dénote un langage soutenu.

Pour désigner le caractère de ce qui est lourd dans le langage courant, j'utiliserais plutôt "lourdeur".

(cette réponse n'engage que moi (France métropolitaine), d'autres francophones pourraient avoir une réponse toute différente)

Comment: "pesanteur" n'est pas vraiment utilisé en physique contrairement à apesanteur (ou impesanteur), gravitation, poids ou masse, par exemple. Pour moi c'est plutôt un terme littéraire.

Comment: Attention que la "lourdeur" de quelquechose ou quelqu'un, ou même d'une action, est souvent employé non pas pour son poids mais pour sa pénibilité.

Comment: @XouDo l'apesanteur est l'absence de pesanteur, si l'un est utilisé, je ne vois pas pourquoi l'autre ne le serait pas (on parle bien de "forte/faible pesanteur" bien que ce soit associé aux forces gravitationnelles)

Comment: @Rafalon évidemment l'apesanteur est l'absence de pesanteur. Le fait que les deux termes existent n’empêche pas forcément que l'un soit plus utilisé que l'autre, dans la physique "grand public" on va dire.